# Why is an anonymous class created when mixing in a trait?

Tags: class, scala, anonymous, mixins

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> trait B
defined trait B
```

Creating an object of class `A` gives us:

```
scala> new A
res4: A = A@11ea3fc
```

But creating an object of class `A` with trait `B` mixed in gives us:

```
scala> new A with B
res3: A with B = $anon$1@172aa3f
```

Here we have an anonymous class (hinted by `anon`). Why ?

Is this because the type `A with B` is regarded as a new type (and which was not defined with an identifier before) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not only because `A with B` has to be regarded as a new type. For the Scala type system, it does not directly matter if there exists a class corresponding to `A with B`. An anonymous class is generated because it has to contain *bridge* methods for all methods in the traits that have been mixed in.

The reason that an anonymous class is created is that the object must have implementations of all the methods from `A` and all the methods from `B`. On the JVM bytecode level, this would warrant inheriting multiple classes, and the multiple inheritance model is not supported on the JVM.

To simulate multiple inheritance (or mixin composition, however you wish to call it), Scala does the following things when you create a trait:

1. If the trait `T` has no method implementations, it creates an interface which defines all the methods in the trait.
2. If the trait `T` has method implementations, it additionally creates a class `T$class` which has a static method for each of the concrete methods in `T`. This static method has the same body as its corresponding method in `T`, but its signature is changed to include the `this` parameter. If `T` had:

   ```
   def foo(x: Int) = x
   ```

then `T$class` will have:

```
<static> def foo($this: T, x: Int) = x
```

The class obtained by mixin composition of some class `A` and some trait `T` will then have a special bridge method generated which forwards the call to the static method which contains the body. This way, the body of the method is not duplicated in every class which mixes in `T`. This is why the anonymous class has to be created - it has to have bridge methods defined for each method in `T`.

Here's an example. When you create a new class by doing mixin composition, e.g. call `new A with T`:

```
class A {
  def bar = println("!")
}

trait T {
  def foo(x: Int) = x
}

new A with T
```

the compiler will rewrite it roughly to something like this:

```
class A {
  def bar = println("!")
}

<interface> T {
  def foo(x: Int): Int
}

class T$class {
  <static> def foo($this: T, x: Int) = x
}

class $anon extends A <implements> T {
  // notice that `bar` is inherited, but `foo` is not
  <bridge> def foo(x: Int) = T$class.foo(this, x)
}
new $anon
```

Notice that the compiler could actually rewrite the callsites to `foo` to call the static methods directly from the callsite, rather than through a bridge method. The reason why it's not done that way is because then it would not support subtyping polymorphism anymore.

Comment: Note that calling `scalac` with the `-Xprint:mixin` argument will show the exact construction that Scala creates. `-Xshow-phases` shows other phases that can be used with `-Xprint:`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. While your *type* is still `A with B`, there needs to be an underlying Java class which implements both interfaces. There is nothing wrong with that, except that if you create objects this way hundreds of times, you will probably have hundreds of class files. In such a case, you may want to create a dedicated `class AB extends A with B` and then instantiate `new AB`.

As a side-note, you will find that you also cannot directly instantiate traits, e.g. `new B` won't work. You need to create an explicit class here, too, e.g. `new B {}`, again resulting in a synthetic ('anonymous') class.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the number of anonymous objects when a dedicated class makes more sense with respect to performance ? 10, 100, 1000 or more ?

Comment: It will only create a new class for every occurrence of this in your code, not for every instance of this class. So unless you have `new A with B` in hundreds of code lines, which is very unlikely, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @John - I don't know. I personally would have a class at 10 cases already; that are 10 different spots where `A with B` is instantiated (as @drexin correctly says). I don't have such cases very often.